# Slang term for 'black-market food' during WW2

Tags: single-word-requests, slang, military

In researching a story set in the U.S.A. during World War II, I came across a slang term for food procured through the black market (not rationing stamps). Now I can’t find where I read it.

In the instance I read, I believe it was a term for a side of beef, but I also believe it could be any food (later, I may stand corrected on that). I’m unsure if the word began with the letter “B,” but it may have.

What was the slang term in the U.S.A. during World War II for black market (i.e., illegal) food?

Comment: Sounds like bootleg.

Comment: It's a bit afield ... but does contraband sound right?

Comment: But the USA did not have food rationing. So how can there have been a black market? There certainly was rationing and a black market in Britain. I don't know if there was a name for such food - but the people who operated it were called "spivs".

Comment: @WS2 Yes, there was [rationing in the US during WWII](https://www.nps.gov/articles/rationing-in-wwii.htm).

Comment: I second @YosefBaskin. *Bootlegging*, while usually associated with alcohol, can apply to anything made or distributed illegally. [This article](https://digitalscholarship.unlv.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1019&context=psi_sigma_siren) uses the term specifically in conjunction with meat.

Comment: @mkennedy Pardon my ignorance. However [this site](https://www.historic-uk.com/CultureUK/Rationing-in-World-War-Two/) will give you an idea of the severity of the rations in Britain. E.g. When my mother was expecting me in 1944, as a pregnant woman she was entitled to 4oz cheese a week (instead of 2ozs) and two eggs instead of one (per week). However as I have said on the history site, my bones are still secure at age 75!

Answer (score 1):

Several historical articles on US rationing during WWII have mentioned "meatlegging", a portmanteau of 'meat' and 'bootlegging', as a term in common use; reportedly almost 20% of US meat production was sold illicitly through various methods during the rationing period.

(Searching for the noun 'meatleggers' also brings up a variety of historical references.)

https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/647379/world-war-ii-black-market-meat
https://www.secretsoftheeasternshore.com/black-market-chicken/
https://www.nps.gov/articles/000/home-front-illicit-trade-and-black-markets-in-world-war-ii.htm
https://www.heinzhistorycenter.org/blog/western-pennsylvania-history-bootleg-beef-black-market-meat-wwii/

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&sca_esv=d6727fb810734362&sca_upv=1&rlz=1CATMUU_enUS1067&sxsrf=ACQVn09krozdRWPh9UAL10dVfL83MDKZJA:1711099474677&q=meatlegging&tbm=bks&source=lnms&prmd=isvnmbtz&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjh6fOixoeFAxUSlIkEHSTKAfgQ0pQJegQIVRAB&biw=1246&bih=638&dpr=1  for some additional info.